# How to set up a django form field to receive data from a request?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, webforms

For multilang, I store the fields in the database as json fields in this format: {"ru": "some text", "en": "some text"},
[add form by itself looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUdq4.png)
input names example: title[ru], title[en]

So i don't know how to write my form to get this data as: title: {"ru": "some", "en":"some"}
What should i do? How to overwrite form field to get data like this?

don’t find answers before that, I decided to completely abandon the forms and collect data with a custom function, but this decision seems to me wrong